# Difference between SendAsync and SendCoreAsync methods in SignalR Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

When updating to the latest version of ASP Net Core and SignalR core, I noticed there are two "send" methods available when sending methods to a client (what used to be InvokeAsync).

After looking at the code comments, both methods are identical in comments, both inherit from IClientProxy, and both accept a string method, object args and then a cancellation token.

What are the differences in these methods? If any? and which should be used when?

Comment: Question is inaccurate, the arguments they receive are not the same.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Quoting `@anurse` from [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2239#issuecomment-387854470):

**Long story short:**

> The **Core** methods **should be ignored** unless you really know what you're doing.

**Short story long:**

> We started with SendAsync, which takes an array of arguments to send:
>
> ```cs
> public void SendAsync(string method, object[] args);
>
> Clients.All.SendAsync("Method", new object[] { arg1, arg2, arg3 });
> ```
>
> Obviously it's a pain to have to create an array every time. The easy
>   fix for that would be to use params:
>
> ```cs
> public void SendAsync(string method, params object[] args);
>
> Clients.All.SendAsync("Method", arg1, arg2, arg3);
> ```
>
> However, that falls apart when you actually want to send an array as a
>   single argument
>
> ```cs
> public void SendAsync(string method, params object[] args);
>
> var arg1 = new object[] { a, b, c };
>
> Clients.All.SendAsync("Method", arg1);
>
> // C# 'params' expands this into the below
>
> Clients.All.SendAsync("Method", a, b, c);
> ```
>
> So instead of sending a single argument that is an array a, b, c,
>   we've sent each of those as separate arguments. This was confusing
>   users.
>
> So we removed the params from it and instead we generate a whole bunch
>   of extension methods that support multiple arguments:
>
> ```cs
> public void SendAsync(string method, object[] args);
> public void SendAsync(string method, object arg1) => SendAsync(method, new object[] { arg1 });
> public void SendAsync(string method, object arg1, object arg2) => SendAsync(method, new object[] { arg1, arg2 });
> // ... etc ...
> ```
>
> But there's still ambiguity when you have code like this:
>
> ```cs
> public void SendAsync(string method, object[] args);
> public void SendAsync(string method, object arg1) => SendAsync(method, new object[] { arg1 });
>
> var arg = new object[] { a, b, c }
>
> Clients.All.SendAsync("method", arg);
> ```
>
> Again, the overload that takes an object[] will be chosen (see this
>   illustration on SharpLab).
>
> So, we renamed the one that takes an array to SendCoreAsync:
>
> ```cs
> public void SendCoreAsync(string method, object[] args);
> public void SendAsync(string method, object arg1) => SendCoreAsync(method, new object[] { arg1 });
>
> var arg = new object[] { a, b, c }
>
> // No ambiguity here!
> Clients.All.SendAsync("method", arg);
> ```

Comment: I love your long story short line!

Comment: it says that 
SencoreAsync 
Does not wait for a response from the receiver.
this means that you dont have to wait for a client reponse and  you can end the request ? can this give some performance ?

Comment: @WilmarArias SendAsync says the same thing

Answer (score 0):

SendCoreAsync use when you need to receive array as argument.
Otherwise if you will send array it will transform to different args